# How to move a directory recursively using Apache commons-io, if destination exists?

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I've been trying to get the following simple code to work and I don't understand why it's failing:

```
File dir = new File("/foo/bar"); // A path to a directory
File destDir = new File("/blah"); // The destination dir

FileUtils.moveDirectoryToDirectory(dir, destDir, !destDir.exists());
```

The `dir` directory contains files and directories. The `destDir` may, or may not contain `bar`.

The error I get is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.io.FileExistsException: Destination '/blah/bar' already exists
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Would the built-in `Files.move(...)` do a better job (I am using JDK 1.8)? I tried that as well, but I couldn't seem to get it to work. This is simple stuff and I can't get why it's so much of an effort to implement...

Comment: *"why it's failing"* and how is it failing?

Comment: Do you mean you want to merge the two directories?

Comment: @MauricePerry, yes! How should I go about it? I'd like to move `bar` under `/blah/bar` and if it exists, then all the contents should be overwritten and any directories merged.

Comment: I'm also willing to consider an approach that doesn't require the apache commons-io, if it would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try `copyDirectoryToDirectory()` instead and then delete the original source...

Comment: Copying files and then deleting them is not very efficient. For example, if you have an SSD, this would have a hardware impact at some point, not to mention the fact that you would need to have twice as much space available in order to have two complete copies before removing one of them.

Comment: @carlspring What I am suggesting is a workaround, `moveDirectoryToDirectory()` is doing essentially the same thing but one subdirectory at a time, it copes complete content of source subdirectory and deletes each source subdirectory recursively.